# Upper bound for the even power of a trinomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

It's easy to get the following estimate for a trinomial to the power of $2$,
$$
(a + b + c)^2 \leq 3a^2 + 3b^2 + 3c^2.
$$
Is there any analogous result for even powers, this is, for the more general case $(a + b + c)^{2n}$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Analogous could be ambiguous here. Does $(a+b+c)^{2n}\leqslant 3^{2n-1}(a^{2n}+b^{2n}+c^{2n})$ qualify?

Comment: That's it!! Any proof?

Comment: Read up on Power Means Inequality or an extended version of Holder can also prove this. You already have an answer, a suitable definition of inner product also can prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "analogous", best I can think of is using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality :

|<u,v>|² $\leq$ <u,u><v,v>

It applies to any pre-hilbert space , so you can produce "analogous" results by varying either the dimension of the space or the definition of inner product before appliying the inequality to well chosen vectors.

For example, take the euclidian space of dimension 3 with the usual definition of inner product. Let u=(x,y,z) and v=(1,1,1)

Applying the inequality gives : (x+y+z)² $\leq$ 3.(x²+y²+z²)

Other spaces will give you other inequalities.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Anthony!! Thanks for your answer :)
By analogous, I mean something like $(a + b + c)^{2n} \leq k(a^{2n} + b^{2n} + c^{2n})$, for a constant $k$.

Comment: Then you should use Holder's Inequality, find more details here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070961/why-this-power-inequality-for-sums-of-real-numbers-holds

To keep things short :
$(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k)^{2n} \leq (k^{2n-1})(x_1^{2n} + x_2^{2n} + ... + x_k^{2n})$